# I need help creating a drop down for another button in my nav bar

Tags: html, css

I would like to create another drop down for "Contact us"" can someone show me how to do it?   I've been trying for do it myself, but it comes out all deformed with this extra unnecessary space.  If someone could help me out I'd really appreciate.   it I have been pulling at my hair all day trying to fix this

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900);
[am-LatoSans] {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
[am-TopLogo] {
    max-height: 70px;
    max-width: 210px;
    margin: 12px 11px;
}
[am-CallNow] {
    font-weight: 200;
    color: green;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}
/*
  Relevant styles below
*/
.topper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#9f9f9f, #535353 3%, #1f1f1f 17%, #212121 49%, #191919 89%, #000000 100%);
  border-top: 1px inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #d1d1d1;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px black, 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  line-height: 24px;

}

.navbar .navbar-nav > li.active {
  color: #f8f8f8;
  background-color: #080808;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -28px 23px -21px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border-left: 1px solid #2A2A2A;
  border-right: 1px solid #272727;
}

.btn.btn-gradient-blue {
  background-color: #0c5497 !important;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #127bde 0%, #072d50 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #127bde 0%, #072d50 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #127bde 0%, #072d50 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff127bde', endColorstr='#ff072d50', GradientType=0);
  border-color: #072d50 #072d50 #0c5497;
  color: #fff !important;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.29);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="stylesheet.css"/>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">   




        <div class="container">
  <!-- Topper w/ logo -->
  <div class="row hidden-xs topper">
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7">
      <a href="//convertify.io"><img am-TopLogo alt="SECUREVIEW"  src="http://blog.convertify.io/assets/images/logo--hero.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-0 text-right ">
      <p am-CallNow>1 (888) CALL - NOW</p>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- End Topper -->
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs-inline-block nav-logo" href="/"><img src="/images/logo-dark-inset.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav js-nav-add-active-class">
            <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="/markets.html">Markets</a></li>
            <li><a href="/buy.html">Buy</a></li>
            <li><a href="/svstrike.html">svStrike</a></li>
            <li><a href="/training.html">Training</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li class="visible-xs-block"><a href="/about.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="visible-xs-block"><a href="/careers.html">Careers</a></li>
            <li class="visible-xs-block"><a href="/press-release.html">Press Release</a></li>
            <li class="visible-xs-block"><a href="https://susteen7.zendesk.com/hc/en-us">Support</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Company <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
                <li><a href="press-release.html">Press Release</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
            <a type="button" class="navbar-btn btn btn-gradient-blue" am-latosans="bold" href="https://susteen7.zendesk.com/hc/en-us">Support</a>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
 </head>

  <body>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
        <!-- SPACER-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
  </body>
```

Comment: You should edit this to be a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you need dropwon in mobile view? or do you need submenu for contactus?

Comment: so you need extra dropdown for contact us in parent dropdown. right??

Comment: I need a drop down in contact us

Comment: yes a drop down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps...
Some changes in html only near your contact us "li" tag

> Replaced this

```
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Contact Us<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/careers.html">Contact 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/press-release.html">Contact 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

> with your

```
<li><a href="/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900);
[am-LatoSans] {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
[am-TopLogo] {
    max-height: 70px;
    max-width: 210px;
    margin: 12px 11px;
}
[am-CallNow] {
    font-weight: 200;
    color: green;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}
/*
  Relevant styles below
*/
.topper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#9f9f9f, #535353 3%, #1f1f1f 17%, #212121 49%, #191919 89%, #000000 100%);
  border-top: 1px inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #d1d1d1;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px black, 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  line-height: 24px;

}

.navbar .navbar-nav > li.active {
  color: #f8f8f8;
  background-color: #080808;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -28px 23px -21px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border-left: 1px solid #2A2A2A;
  border-right: 1px solid #272727;
}

.btn.btn-gradient-blue {
  background-color: #0c5497 !important;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #127bde 0%, #072d50 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #127bde 0%, #072d50 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #127bde 0%, #072d50 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff127bde', endColorstr='#ff072d50', GradientType=0);
  border-color: #072d50 #072d50 #0c5497;
  color: #fff !important;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.29);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="stylesheet.css"/>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">   




        <div class="container">
  <!-- Topper w/ logo -->
  <div class="row hidden-xs topper">
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7">
      <a href="//convertify.io"><img am-TopLogo alt="SECUREVIEW"  src="http://blog.convertify.io/assets/images/logo--hero.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-0 text-right ">
      <p am-CallNow>1 (888) CALL - NOW</p>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- End Topper -->
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs-inline-block nav-logo" href="/"><img src="/images/logo-dark-inset.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav js-nav-add-active-class">
            <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="/markets.html">Markets</a></li>
            <li><a href="/buy.html">Buy</a></li>
            <li><a href="/svstrike.html">svStrike</a></li>
            <li><a href="/training.html">Training</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Contact Us<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="/careers.html">Contact 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/press-release.html">Contact 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
            <li class="visible-xs-block"><a href="/about.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="visible-xs-block"><a href="/careers.html">Careers</a></li>
            <li class="visible-xs-block"><a href="/press-release.html">Press Release</a></li>
            <li class="visible-xs-block"><a href="https://susteen7.zendesk.com/hc/en-us">Support</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Company <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
                <li><a href="press-release.html">Press Release</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
            <a type="button" class="navbar-btn btn btn-gradient-blue" am-latosans="bold" href="https://susteen7.zendesk.com/hc/en-us">Support</a>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
 </head>

  <body>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
        <!-- SPACER-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
  </body>
```

Comment: You sir are amazing!  Big thank you this is exactly what I was looking for brother!    Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!